# AngularJS - Image onload directive - this' reference not working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive as follows:

```
.directive('ngImageOnLoad', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {

                  scope.$apply(function (){
                      scope.$eval(attrs.ngImageOnLoad);
                  });

                  event.preventDefault();

            });
        }
    };
})
```

My HTML img tag looks like follows:

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" ng-image-on-load="onImageLoad(this)" />
```

In my controller i have:

```
    $scope.imageOnLoad = function(theImg)
    {
        console.log("theImg is: " + theImg); //This prints [Object Object]
        console.log("theImg.src: " + theImg.src); //This prints UNDEFINED!!
    }
```

**Question:**
Why is the 'this' reference not working properly. 
 
I need access to image's src attribute in my function imageOnLoad. But it is UNDEFINED!

Comment: Use `element` instead. I'm sure `this` in the context probably refers to the parent scope or controller (not sure). Also you could use `call` instead of `eval`: `attrs.ngImageOnLoad.call(element)`

Comment: additionally bind('load'...) must be called before you set img.src, maybe you should use ng-src instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a fiddle for you.. checkout [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavalcengg/V6MLF/9/)

```
              scope.$apply(function (){
                  //scope.$eval(attrs.ngImageOnLoad);
                  $parse(attrs.ngImageOnLoad)(scope, {'this': element[0]});
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the target property from the event object:

```
.directive('ngImageOnLoad', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function(evt) {

                  scope.$apply(function (){
                      scope.$eval(attrs.ngImageOnLoad, { $element: evt.target});
                  });

                  evt.preventDefault();

            });
        }
    };
})
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" ng-image-on-load="onImageLoad($element)" />
```

Controller

```
$scope.imageOnLoad = function(theImg)
{
    console.log("theImg is: " + theImg); //This prints [Object Object]
    console.log("theImg.src: " + theImg.src); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want through the `$event` ([ref](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)). Get the element through on of event's methods ([ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event)), e.g.:

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg" ng-image-on-load="onImageLoad($event)" />
```

And:

```
$scope.onImageLoad = function($event) {
    console.log("theImg.src: " + $event.target.src);
}
```

---

**Edit:**

As pointed out in the comments, the `$event` is not available like this. The correct way, as *already answered* by pixelbits and Kasper Lewau, is to use `$eval`. For the sake of completeness, let me include this here too:

The link function would change as:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    var cb = $parse(attrs.ngImageOnLoad);
    element.bind('load', function(event) {
        scope.$apply(function() {
            cb({'$event':event});
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: With that i get this error message: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined" at this line:  console.log("theImg.src: " + $event.target.src);

Comment: You are right - the `$event` is not available in your implementation. Check out the answer from pixelbits for a correct way to put it in scope using `$eval`.